# GLM model with a Tweedie distribution

Tags: python, glm, statsmodels, tweedie

I am trying to build a GLM model in Python. I am using statsmodel and based on the domain knowledge that I have in insurance, my dependent variable has Tweedie distribution. Following is the piece of code I have used:

```
practice_model = practice_model = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family = sm.families.Tweedie(link = sm.families.links.log))
practice_results = practice_model.fit()
```

I get an error as: `module 'statsmodels.genmod.families' has no attribute 'Tweedie'`

Can someone please help me to understand what part of my model/syntax is incorrect?

P.S: I was able to build the GLM model using a Gamma Family.

Comment: Do you have version 0.8 or newer? Try direct import: `from statsmodels.genmod.families.family import Tweedie` to see if that works.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work.

Comment: Then I guess your version of statsmodels is too old.